# Push viewController from CollectionView cell programmatically not working - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I am a new iOS programming. Now i am creating a sample app by not using `storyboard` which i implemented `UICollectionView` for the main class which scroll direction is vertical. A particular cell i added another `UICollectionView` for horizontal direction. The problem is that `cell` which horizontal scroll direction is not pushing to another view controller which i click on it.

Here is `rootViewController` that i setup in `AppDelegate`

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: CategoryController())
window?.rootViewController = navigation
```

Here is `CategoryController` which i implement `tableView`

```
tableView.register(TableCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 120
}
```

For `tableView` when i click on particular cell is working fine when i want to navigate to a particular controller

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.item)
    let view = DetailEachCellController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
}
```

The problem is that in `DetailEachCellController` i use `UICollectionView` for list down some data, and when i click on particular cell is not navigate to new controller

Here `DetailEachCellController` as `UIViewController`

```
var collectionDetailView: UICollectionView!
collectionDetailView.register(DetailContactCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdContact)
collectionDetailView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdContent)

func setupCollectionView() {
    collectionDetailView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailContent.topAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionDetailView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailContent.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionDetailView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    collectionDetailView.backgroundColor = .white 
}

func callAction() {
    print("pushing view")
    let view = UIViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
}
```

Here the delegate for `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

```
extension DetailEachCellController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if indexPath.item == 0 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdContact, for: indexPath)

            return cell
        }
        else {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdContent, for: indexPath)
            cell.backgroundColor = .blue
            return cell
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if indexPath.item == 1 {
          return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 250)
        }
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 120)
    }
}
```

Here is `DetailContactCell` which i added some buttons for user click and more to next view, but it is not moving but the function is called.

```
class DetailContactCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var eachCellController: DetailEachCellController?

lazy var callButton: UIButton = {

    let button = UIButton()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
    button.backgroundColor = .white
    button.setTitle("CALL", for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 10)
    button.layer.shadowRadius = 10
    return button
}()
lazy var bookButton: UIButton = {

    let button = UIButton()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
    button.backgroundColor = .white
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 10)
    button.layer.shadowRadius = 10
    return button
}()
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    addSubview(callButton)
    addSubview(bookButton)
    callButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    callButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
    callButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/2.5).isActive = true
    callButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true

    bookButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    bookButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
    bookButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/2.5).isActive = true
    bookButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true

    self.actionButton()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func actionButton() {
    callButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(callBtn), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func callBtn() {
    print("calling")
    eachCellController = DetailEachCellController()
    eachCellController?.callAction()
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdContact, for: indexPath) as! DetailContactCell
        // Here is line add to `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`
        cell.eachCellController = self

        return cell
    }else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdContent, for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .blue
        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because this

//  eachCellController = DetailEachCellController() // comment it

is another VC not the presented one

```
eachCellController?.callAction()
```

you need to send self  in `cellForItemAt`

```
cell.eachCellController = self
```

//

```
@objc func callBtn() {
   print("calling")
   eachCellController?.callAction()
}
```

Comment: Passing a strong instance of the `UIViewController` handling the `UICollectionView` to the `UICollectionViewCell` object is not good. This is vulnerable to retain cycle. Delegation pattern and handlers are made to fit in such cases.

Comment: @Malloc he can declare it weak

Answer (score 2):

You can't push a new view controller to the navigation controller stack from inside the `UICollectionViewCell` class.

The way to do so is to tell the `DetailEachCellController`(through a delegate method or a callback handler) that the button was clicked, then **ONLY FROM** `DetailEachCellController` you can push the view controller.

Here is a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704441/propagate-a-custom-event-from-a-uicollectionviewcell)

Comment: Thank for your wonderful explanation. I will try to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

It is not convenient way to pass the strong object of `UIViewController` to cell. You may create retain cycle and your view controller will never been released as well as memory so it may cause a memory issue in future

To Fix this you may have following options

1. Use Delegate
2. Use Closure
3. Implement Button action in viewcontroller itself with `addTarget`

As closure option is easy I am giving you a example to implement it.

In your collection view cell  add following  Property

```
var callBtnTapped : (() -> ())?
```

Now in .

```
@objc func callBtn() {
    print("calling") 
     // Check that target has implemented closure ? 
     if let clouser = self.callBtnTapped {
            clouser(screenShotID)
      }
}
```

In your view controller  `cellForItem` add body to closure

```
     cell.callBtnTapped = {[weak self]  in
        guard let strongSelf = self   else  {return}
        strongSelf. callAction()
        // It will be called when button tapped 
    }
```

Hope it is helpful

Comment: This is also what i am looking and very helpful for me.

Comment: @SamboPisal glad that it is helpful to you